# A good matplot tutorial (from beginner to intermidiate)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Can anyone recommend a good matplot tutorial. I am a complete beginner - but have used similar software (matlab, R etc), in my halcyon days at University (i.e. a long time ago).

A google search brings up a list of dubious quality, and the 'official' docs are too terse, or provide examples that are more 'edge case' (e.g. drawing dolphins swimming in a bubble), than one is likely to meet in practise.

I want a manual that provides the following information in a well structured manner:

1. Introduction to the data types
2. Introduction to 2D plotting with some simple practical examples (simple 2D graphs)
3. Introduction to 3D plotting with some simple practical examples (simple 2D graphs: contour and surface)

**[Edit]**

I'm new to both Python and matplot (but not new to programming - I have a C/C++ background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice book called [**"Matplotlib for Python Developers"**](https://www.packtpub.com/matplotlib-python-development/book)

It doesn't cover 3D graphics, though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a beginner with programming, Python, or just matplotlib? Because each of those will provide entirely different points of entry. I'm quite competent with Python, but I had not used matplotlib so much... however, the [gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) has examples of different types of graphs and it's usually somewhat simple to convert the examples to your own use-case.

It's also a lot easier if you know PyGTK since they use a fair amount of said library in matplotlib.

Edit:

Also, Ipython in [pylab](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/shell.html) mode is really good for exploring the objects, methods, and modules in pylab.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful:

Getting started with Matplotlib
http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=7200090&fromSeriesID=720

Answer (score 0):

A 10-page tutorial: [Raymond](http://physics.nmt.edu/~raymond/software/python_notes/paper004.html)
Not a tutorial, but more examples:
[scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib)

(@morpeous, if you know of any good tutorials of the kind you'd like,
please post them — might motivate someone.)

Answer (score 0):

Good one for begineers:
See some sample from the below link

https://sites.google.com/site/scigraphs/tutorial#TOC-Simple-plot--font-size-2-